# How to create a source map for my compiled JS files with mincer?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp, source-maps, mincer

I want to compile some coffeescript files into one JS file using [mincer](http://github.com/nodeca/mincer) and [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). I have an app.coffee file which requires all other files. My gulp task uses [gulp-mincer](http://github.com/jisaacks/gulp-mincer) and looks like that:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var Mincer = require('mincer');
var mince = require('gulp-mincer');

gulp.task('mincer', function(){
  var env = new Mincer.Environment();
  env.enable('source_maps');
  env.appendPath('src/coffee');

  return gulp.src('src/coffee/**/app.*')
    .pipe(mince(env))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
```

If I run this task I get one JS file with all required code in it but no source map. What I have to do to get also the source map file?

Comment: Have you managed to complete this task?